# How to programmatically load a specific file for NCache client configuration?

Tags: ncache

Not wanting to leave a `client.ncconf` lying aside my `exe`, I wish to be able to specify the path to the `client.ncconf` file programatically. How may I? I am using NCache 4.4SP1 Open Source.

The methods I am using are mainly `Web.Caching.NCache.InitializeCache` and `Cache.Get`.

Answer (score 1):

It picks the config from <s>`%NCHOME%`</s> `InstallDir/config`.
Just add the following in your AppSettings

```xml
<add key="InstallDir" value="C:\temp"/>
```

Also, all the client configurations can be specified programmatically using the `CacheInitParams`. You can

```cs
namespace Alachisoft.NCache.Web.Caching
{
    public class CacheInitParams : ICloneable
    {
        public CacheInitParams();

        public string BindIP { get; set; }
        public ClientCacheSyncMode ClientCacheSyncMode { get; set; }
        public int ClientRequestTimeOut { get; set; }
        public int CommandRetries { get; set; }
        public int CommandRetryInterval { get; set; }
        public int ConnectionRetries { get; set; }
        public int ConnectionTimeout { get; set; }
        public string DefaultReadThruProvider { get; set; }
        public string DefaultWriteThruProvider { get; set; }
        public bool LoadBalance { get; set; }
        public CacheMode Mode { get; set; }
        [Obsolete("This property is deprecated. Please use the 'ServerList' property instead.", false)]
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public SecurityParams PrimaryUserCredentials { get; set; }
        public int RetryConnectionDelay { get; set; }
        public int RetryInterval { get; set; }
        public SecurityParams SecondaryUserCredentials { get; set; }
        [Obsolete("This property is deprecated. Please use the 'ServerList' property instead.", false)]
        public string Server { get; set; }
        public CacheServerInfo[] ServerList { get; set; }

        public object Clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know at what time it evaluates the `%NCHOME%` variable? Would setting the environment variable at the beginning of the program be enough to change the location?

Comment: I am sorry Basit, but `App.config` does not qualify for "programatically". I only know the directory containing the `client.ncconf` the from the command line parameters of my app.

Comment: Use [ConfigurationManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA does it help ?

Comment: @BasitAnwer this answer didnt solve, ncache still cant find the client.nconf, even putting the file on the same path of the application